# winding number example

Tags: complex-analysis

Let 
$$\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb C $$ be a closed curve and$$
Int(y)=\{z\in\mathbb C-tra(\gamma): ind(z)\neq0\}, \\
Ext(y)=\{z\in\mathbb C-tra(\gamma): ind(z)=0\}, $$ 
where $ind(z)\;$is the winding number.

Are there any examples where $Int(\gamma)$ and $Ext(\gamma)$ are not connected ?

Comment: What is $y$ and what is $tra(\gamma$ (one parenthesis?)

Comment: I think that "tra" denotes the "trace" of the curve (i.e., the image of the function $\gamma$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $C_1,C_2,C_3$ be the circles $|z| = 1, |z-2|=1, |z-4|=1.$ Starting at $1,$ let $\gamma$ be the closed contour that traces out the bottom half of $C_2,$ then traces once around all of $C_3,$ then traces the top half of $C_2.$ That brings us back to $1.$ We're not done: Continue $\gamma$ to go once around $C_1$ with positive orientation, then once around $C_1$ with negative orentation. We're back at $1,$ so $\gamma $ is closed. Then the winding number of $\gamma$ inside $C_1$ and $C_2$ are both $1,$ the winding number inside $C_1$ is $0,$ and the winding number in the exterior of all three circles is $0.$ Thus both $\text { Int }\gamma,\text { Ext }\gamma$ are not connected.

Answer (score 1):

If $\gamma$ is a continuous and non-self-intersecting loop, then the interior and exterior are each connected; that's the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem). However, that doesn't hold if $\gamma$ intersects itself. Consider a [lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate): it partitions the plane into one unbounded region with winding number zero, and two bounded regions with winding number one. WolframAlpha gives [a parametrization of a lemniscate](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lemniscate).

Comment: I was actually thinking of a lemniscate. Just couldn't come up with a parametrization. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=lemniscate%20parametric

Comment: I added a link to a parametrization for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you define, on $[a, b] = [0, 1]$

$$
\gamma(t) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{2t-1} - 1 & t > \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2t-1} + 1 & t < \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & t = \frac{1}{2} 
\end{cases}
$$

then one of those two regions consists of all of $\mathbb C$ except for the $x$-axis, which is disconnected. The other is empty. Of course, the function I've defined isn't even continuous, so you have to expect this sort of thing.

You probably meant to write "suppose that $\gamma: [a, b] \to \mathbb C$ is a continuous (or even differentiable?) function with $\gamma(a) = \gamma(b)$. Then ... "

This example shows that those missing hypotheses are important.

Comment: ...and now you've edited the problem to include the idea that $\gamma$ is a loop.